# MS-Access How can I look up the value from another table?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have create a query only contain the information I need.
each jobs may have different pricing method, I would like to pick up the price from a standardized price list. Can someone give me a hand?

Pricing Method : A-D     Quantity: 1-10

Each Job can use different method

Query:

Job Number             Pricing Method           Quantity

00001                      A                    10

00002                      A                    3

00003                      C                    1

00004                      D                    5

.....

...

etc.

the standardized table create as the price of each type and each quantity

Price List:

Pricing Method       Quantity         Price

```
  A                  1              10

  A                  2              12

  A                  3              14

  A                  4              16

  A                  5              18

  A                  6              19

 ....              ...              ...

  A                 10              23

 ...               ...              ...

  B                ...              ...

  C                ...              ...

  D                 10              100

etc....
```

How can I build my query to get the according price???
Thank you in advance!!!

Sorry, I cant figure out the "formatting", image attached.

[Table and Query looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w38Cv.png)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, Try it.

```
SELECT tblJobs.*, tblPrices.Quantity, tblPrices.Price, *
FROM tblJobs INNER JOIN tblPrices ON (tblJobs.Quantity = tblPrices.Quantity) 
AND (tblJobs.[Pricing method] = tblPrices.[Pricing Method]);
```

Comment: It works !!! 
In my case, my "standardized table" the primary key is  (method and quantity).

And you showed me how to join the table with 2 key. 
 
Thank you Jim :)